# GoogleApp Engine `war was too large`

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My war is 54mb with all jars. Is 32mb the max appengine will use? My application is a basic maven web project with jersey, shiro, and mysql. Am i missing a step to make the war file smaller or set appengine to allow a larger file? 32MB seems like a very small maximum limit.

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LocalIOException: File /var/folders/b7/jhmrd7rs3rjf702nwf72572m0000gn/T/appcfg2995443218949418441.tmp/1-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war is too large (limit 32000000 bytes).
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.scanFiles(AppVersionUpload.java:294)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.uploadFilesTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:220)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:572)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:57)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:438)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. my war is 36MB and couldn't deploy to GAE. Any luck?

Comment: @Jaison I was attempting to use the eclipse plugin to deploy my maven project. I believe the eclipse plugin was trying to push everything from my target directory which included my 54mb war file. I ended up using `mvn appengine:deploy` and was finally able to get it to push my war even though my war file size did not change. Also the documentation will tell you to run `mvn appengine:update` which, apparently, is not an available goal in version 1.0.0 for appengine sdk. Maybe my project setup was incorrect.